# The function 'connect()' returns a value, but this value is never used. What does this mean?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I am new to Godot, and I am creating my first project. There's something that annoys the heck out of me. It's this: "The function 'connect()' returns a value, but this value is never used." I don't know what to add to the line of code, but I will first show the code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var gravity = 1000
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var maxHorizontalSpeed = 120
var horizontalAcceleration = 100
var jumpSpeed = 320
var jumpTerminationMultiplier = 4
var hasDoubleJump = false

func _ready():
 warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
$HazardArea.connect("area_entered", self, "on_hazard_area_entered")

func _process(delta):
    var moveVector = Vector2.ZERO
    moveVector.x = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    moveVector.y = -1 if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") else 0
    velocity.x += moveVector.x * horizontalAcceleration * delta
    if (moveVector.x == 0):
        velocity.x = lerp(0, velocity.x, pow(2, -50))
        
    velocity.x = clamp(velocity.x,  -maxHorizontalSpeed, maxHorizontalSpeed)
    
    if (moveVector.y < 0 && (is_on_floor() || $CoyoteTimer.is_stopped() || hasDoubleJump)):
        velocity.y = moveVector.y * jumpSpeed
        if(!is_on_floor() && $CoyoteTimer.is_stopped()):
            hasDoubleJump = false
        $CoyoteTimer.stop()
    if(moveVector.y < 0 && !Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump")):
        velocity.x = gravity * jumpTerminationMultiplier * delta
    else:
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    var wasOnFloor = is_on_floor()
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

    if(wasOnFloor && !is_on_floor()):
        $CoyoteTimer.start()

    if(is_on_floor()):
        hasDoubleJump = true

    update_animation()

func get_movement_vector():
    var moveVector = Vector2.ZERO
    moveVector.x = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    moveVector.y = -1 if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") else 0
    return moveVector

func update_animation():
    var moveVec = get_movement_vector()
    if(!is_on_floor()):
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Jump")
    elif(moveVec.x != 0):
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Run")      
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Idle")

    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true if moveVec.x > 0 else false
    
func on_hazard_area_entered(_area2d):
    print("die")
```

The problem is on line 13, and I would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

there is not a solution for this problem. The only thinks you can do are these:

1. Or use the returning value (if you want)
2. Or press ignore in warning tab

This link can help you more https://godotengine.org/qa/78337/the-function-connect-returns-value-but-this-value-never-used

Comment: I am curious what the returning value is!